# add all dto fields into query object if doesn't into query NestJs

Tags: javascript, request, nestjs

I've been working in NestJs. I try to add in the object of `@Query()`, all the fields that were not entered in the query:

Dto:

```
{
    a: number = null
    b: number = null
    c: number = null
}
```

Ex request:

```
POST url?a=5
```

I get:

```
query = {a:5}
```

I need:

```
query = {a: 5, b: null, c: null}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable the transformation on `ValidationPipe` like so: `new ValidationPipe({ transform: true })`

The default is `false` for performance reasons (I guess), which makes that `query` not an instance of your DTO